# i'm unable to access IIS website using public ip with non-80 port

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting

On virtual machine i install `IIS`  and host website with `port 80`.i accessed it locally using `localhost` and from my laptop using public IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80`, it accessed perfectly in both case.when i publish another website on `IIS` using `port 81` and access it locally using `localhost:81`, it runs , but when i access it publically on my laptop using public IP `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81` it can't be accessed and error occurs

> This site can’t be reached.

**i also add inbound rule for port 81 in firewall,even not accessed.**

how i can access it using public ip on other network?

Comment: Which public IP address? The WAN IP assigned to your router by the ISP? Some ISP blocks non 80 ports, and sometimes even port 80. So to host a web site, usually you need to buy hosting services (like AWS or Azure).

Comment: how we can check _WAN IP assigned to your router by the ISP or not?_ or _ip block non80 port?_ in any case is there any way to assigned WAN IP to router by the ISP or unlock non 80 port?@LexLi?

Comment: You may contact your ISP and they should know whether  non 80 port has been blocked. Some IAAS virtual machine also need to enable 81 port in their portal gateway. Besides, some third-party software would block the access via 81 and you may need to check with that.

Comment: thank you ..i connect with ISP...JokiesDing